# Books which defines higher differentials in algebraic curves context

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading an article which mentions a lot about higher differentials:

[image]

I don't know what is $\Omega^n(F)$, my background is just [Fulton's Algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) which defines just $\Omega(F)$.

I need a book which explains which defines higher differentials in this context.

I really need help!

Many thanks

**Remark**

The link for the article I mentioned in this [link](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416), the author writes about higher differentials in the chapter 2.

Comment: There will be no book about higher differentials in the context of algebraic curves. Over a smooth variety, $\Omega^n$ is the $n$-th exterior power of a locally free sheaf of rank equal the dimension of the variety. So for curves, there is only $\Omega^1$. Higher differentials are explained e.g. in the book of Hartshorne (for algebraic geometry), the book of Griffiths-Harris (for complex algebraic geometry) or Bott-Tu (differentiable manifolds).

Comment: @MatthiasWendt So is there some book I can read with my background (Fulton's algebraic curves book)?

Comment: As in Matthias's comment, $\Omega^n$ is often the $n$-th exterior power of $\Omega^1$ which doesn't give anything for curves, but I think what you want is the $n$-th tensor power of $\Omega^1$, which makes sense for curves.

Comment: In terms of divisors, if $K$ is the canonical divisor, you are looking at $nK-F$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch do you know where can I find this definition of $\Omega^n$ you mentioned for curves?

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega^n(F)=\Lambda^n\Omega(F)$

About differentials see, for example, R. Hartshorne "Algebraic Geometry" (Chapter 2 "Scemes", $\S8$ "Differentials").
Or, for more details, see Igor R. Shafarevish "Basic Algebraic Geometry 1" (Chapter III "Divisors and differential forms", $\S5$ "Differential $p$-forms").

Comment: As Felipe Voloch's comment explains, in this context $\Omega^n$ does _not_ mean exterior power, since that would be useless for curves.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh so what is $\Omega^n$ in this context? just the tensor product of the $\Omega$'s?

Comment: @user42912: yes, $\Omega^n$ is supposed to mean tensor power here. (This is bad notation, in my opinion.)